# Dynamic values in inline JSON-LD script block

Tags: dynamic, json-ld

I have data stored in a DB that I select and echo on my html page like so:

```
 <article id="content_left_article_1">
      <h1 class="main-heading">Get in Touch</h1>
      <P><?php echo $rs_contactRows['ContactJobTitle']; ?>: <?php echo $rs_contactRows['ContactName']; ?></P>
      <P>Email: <?php echo $rs_contactRows['ContactEmail']; ?></P>
      <P>Mobile: <?php echo $rs_contactRows['ContactTelephone']; ?></P>
 </article>
```

I know I can easily mark up data for this person with JSON-LD in a separate script block on the page with something like this:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
    {
      "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
      "@type": "person",
      "name": "Brian Keet",
      "jobTitle": "Director",
      "url": "http://tekiahfoundation.blogspot.co.za/",
      "email": "briankeet@yahoo.com",
      "telephone": "+27766261024"
    }
    </script>
```

However, if the client were to update any of those details in the DB (which they most certainly will through the sites CMS), the static JSON-LD script block above will stay... well, static. I've been googling and stack-overflowing like mad trying to find an answer on how to have a dynamic value in a JSON-LD script block,

```
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
    {
      "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
      "@type": "person",
      "name": "$user.name + $user.surname",
    }
    </script>
```

or some other approach, that passes Googles structured data testing tools checks.

I've been trying to figure out how to work with a json_encoded($dataObject) which I get using the below mysqli_query() etc in php (see below code), and maybe create a JSON-LD script block with javascript but I'm not quite sure how this would work. I also know that apparently "Google can read JSON-LD data even when it is dynamically injected into the page's contents, such as by Javascript code or embedded 'widgets'". Also, if I echo the result of the json_encoded mysqli_fetch_assoc:

```
<?php
   require('inc-conncvnl.php');
   require('inc-function-escapestring.php');
   $sql_contact = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tblcontact");
   $rs_contact = mysqli_query($vconncvnl, $sql_contact);
   $rs_contactRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_contact);
   $contactData = json_encode($rs_contactRows);
  echo $contactData;
?>
```

I get the data echoing on page, like so:[json-encode echo on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikQfV.png)

I'm pretty sure I'm missing some big pieces of this puzzle. If anyone can help me figure out a successful approach to solving this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Note sure I follow, but … why don’t you echo the data from the DB for your JSON-LD in the same way you do it for the HTML? And just in case you don’t know: instead of JSON-LD (in a separate `script` element) you could use Microdata or RDFa (which gets added to your existing HTML).

Comment: @unor Well Micro and RDF are also good but JSON-LD is recommended, tho Google.com uses Microdata

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either just output the JSON-LD in PHP as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "<?php echo htmlentities($rs_contactRows['ContactName'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>",
  "jobTitle": "<?php echo htmlentities($rs_contactRows['ContactJobTitle'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>",
  "url": "<?php echo htmlentities($rs_contactRows['ContactUrl'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>",
  "email": "<?php echo htmlentities($rs_contactRows['ContactEmail'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>",
  "telephone": "<?php echo htmlentities($rs_contactRows['ContactTelephone'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>"
}
</script>
```

or you create the JSON-LD in PHP and output that:

```
$data = array(
  '@context' => 'http://schema.org/',
  '@type' => 'Person',
  'name' => $rs_contactRows['ContactName'],
  'jobTitle' => $rs_contactRows['ContactJobTitle'],
  'url' => $rs_contactRows['ContactUrl'],
  'email' => $rs_contactRows['ContactEmail'],
  'telephone' => $rs_contactRows['ContactTelephone']
);
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Side note: You should always use `htmlentities` when outputting HTML as otherwise you risk [XSS security vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: I ended up building a massive string with the correct formatting in php, calling it in on the html page and just echoing it. 

The source code it produces passed Googles structured data testing checks. I don't know why I just didn't think of echoing the values in my JSON script block like you did in the first example. I think I kept on getting confused by what the crawlers will read...

Thank you for your clear answer, I'll try both options and see what feels better, they're both cleaner than my monster string I ended up creating.

Answer (score 1):

Markus answer is right way to understand the basis.
Next step could be to find and use a php library that generate LD-JSON for you.

For example, let's have a look at [Torann](https://github.com/Torann/json-ld) json-ld library.

You could install it using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)  by updating `composer.json` : add the following dependency:

> "require": {
>       "torann/json-ld": "^0.0"   }

Then in you page, you could generate ld-json this way (cf. Readme or Unit tests):

```
$context = \JsonLd\Context::create('news_article', [
    'headline' => 'Article headline',
    'description' => 'A most wonderful article',
    'mainEntityOfPage' => [
        'url' => 'https://google.com/article',
    ],
    'image' => [
        'url' => 'https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg',
        'height' => 800,
        'width' => 800,
    ],
    'datePublished' => '2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00',
    'dateModified' => '2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00',
    'author' => [
        'name' => 'John Doe',
    ],
    'publisher' => [
        'name' => 'Google',
        'logo' => [
          'url' => 'https://google.com/logo.jpg',
          'width' => 600,
          'height' => 60,
        ]
    ],
]);

echo $context; // Will output the script tag
```

NB/ if [Person](https://github.com/Torann/json-ld/blob/master/src/ContextTypes/Person.php) context need to be improved, open an [issue](https://github.com/Torann/json-ld/issues) with your needs (I can fix it), or submit a pull request yourself.